# qtcreator cmake "No executable specified"

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-14.10

Im having a very annoying issue with qtcreator and cmake projects: qtcreator fails to find the executable. It just prints **"No executable specified"** when trying to launch any executable from the IDE. Everything works fine after configuring the project (first time only). The issue manifests when loading the project afterwards. Only workaround is deleting the "CMakeLists.txt.user" before every use. This is tedious and unnecessary.

This is happening to projects that were running just fine for years, both my own and my colleagues, on multiple machines running ubuntu 14.04 & 14.10. Problems started with qtcreator version 3 and higher from ubuntu 14.04 upwards.

Assuming that the issue is triggered by some changes in the "CMakeLists.txt.user", after the project is closed the first time, I replaced the file with a copy of it right after it was created the first time. This worked, thus confirming that there is either something wrong with the file itself, or changes to it trigger an existing bug in qt-creator. Unfortunately it is just as tedious as deleting the file in the first place.

**My Challenge:**
Unfortunately I am not familiar with the inner workings of qtcreaor, however I managed to identify the specific config lines that are responsible. **What does qtcreator actually change here?**

[image]

Please note that "racoon" is the project name and the above diff screenshot is much larger than formatted by stackoverflow (right-click to view full resolution).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i had exactly the same problem using Ubuntu 14.10 and resolved it by doing the following:

1. Get ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/a/an/anthonos/mirror/os3-next/os3-rpm/q/qtcreator-3.1.2-0.x86_64.rpm
2. Extract the file /usr/lib/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject/libCMakeProjectManager.so
3. Overwrite this file at
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/ ( at least on x64)
   in your system

This will replace the cmake plugin which is currently version 3.1.1 with 3.1.2 which will make the problem disappear !

Comment: I saw that workaround in several place. Didn't work for me though: incompatible with my Qt installation (version mismatch). I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with qtcreator installed from the ubuntu repo

Answer (score 1):

I installed qtcreator using [Qt's own installer](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-qt-creator-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) instead of the one provided by Ubuntu. It installs version 5.3.1 and fixes the problem.

Comment: Qt Creator is at 3.3.1 last I checked. I think you have a typo.